# How to add elements in Vec like a binary tree's leaf nodes?

Tags: chisel

assuming n = 2^x elements in Vec，

adding elements in Vec using

```
vec.reduce(_ +& _)
```

will end up with element width = w + 2^x - 1

if adding them for every two elements like a tree， the width will be w + x

seems

```
vec.par.reduce(_ +& _)
```

works for 4 elements, but not for 8 or 16.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the experimental `Interval` type in chisel3. There's some limited documentation [here](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.4.3/chisel3/experimental/Interval.html). Intervals were designed for just this situation. You shouldn't even have to change everything, just map the elements of your Vec to Intervals and then reduce them.

Answer (score 0):

`chisel3.Vec` has a `reduceTree` method that will do what you want:

```scala
class Example extends MultiIOModule {
  val in = IO(Input(Vec(8, UInt(8.W))))
  val out = IO(Output(UInt())) // Infers width to be 11
  
  out := in.reduceTree(_ +& _)
}
```

Scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rhm4je13T0ykEtRS7P7mfQ

Also see the Vec API docs: https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/Vec.html